# The AQFT defined by ordinary NRQM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

It is often said that NRQM is one dimensional QFT. The Haag-Kastler axioms for QFT should apply to NRQM also then.*

So, for the NRQM system $L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)$ with time evolution given by 
$$U_t = \exp\left(-itH\right)$$
$$ = \exp\left(-it\frac{p^2}{2m}\right)$$
$$ = \exp\left(it\frac{\Delta}{2m}\right)$$
What is the corresponding net of algebras? I would have thought that the spacetime regions $\mathcal{O}$ would become time intervals $\left[t,t'\right]$ but then I'm not sure what the algebra of observables of this region should be.

Obviously, the locality axiom about space-like separated regions having commuting algebras is trivial here.

*If the starred statement at the top is wrong, can you explain this?

Answer (score 1):

When thinking of NRQM as a QFT in one-dimensional spacetime, the Haag-Kaslter axioms become trivial in the sense that all of the local algebras are *equal* to each other (not just isomorphic, but *equal*). Working in the Heisenberg picture as always in AQFT, the observables associated with any finite interval of time — such as the position operators $\vec X(t)$ — generate the full algebra of observables, so the "local" algebras associated with all finite intervals of time are equal to each other. This is just the time-slice axiom (aka primitive causality) applied to the case of zero-dimensional space, where a Cauchy surface consists of a single point.

A more interesting way to relate NRQM to QFT is to think of NRQM as the single-particle sector of a strictly non-relativistic QFT. Non-relativistic QFT can be regarded as a net of algebras of observables similarly to relativistic AQFT, except that instead of open regions of spacetime, we consider regions of the form $(S,t)$ where $S$ is an open region of *space* and $t$ is a single time. Isotony, the time-slice axiom (primitive causality), microcausality, and the spectrum condition all have fairly obvious analogues in the non-relativistic case. This might not be useful for proving theorems, but it's still useful as an intuitive framework, just like the usual AQFT axioms are in the relativistic case.